# How to use woocommerce functions outside of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to use woocommerce functions outside of wordpress.  I have included the code below to use wordpress functions outside of wordpress:

```
 <?php
 require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-blog-header.php');
?
```

What other code do i have to include so woocommerce functions are accessible?

Comment: Why do you want to use woocommerce functions outside of wordpress ??

Comment: I want to get order details and use mpdf to create a pdf file, so i need functions such as `get_order()`.   Do you know a way to get order details with using WP_Query?

Comment: Why can't you use the mpdf library inside wordpress???

Comment: my mpdf folder is located in wp-content, it isn't a template it is a custom php file.

Comment: You could try using the [WooCommerce API](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#orders)

Comment: Make it a plugin. Then either make a custom template for your theme or shortcodes or admin backend if that is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply including the wp-load.php in the file you want to use the WooCommerce/WordPress functionality is enough (as long as the website is properly set up).