# wc_get_product_ids_on_sale() ...getting product on sale in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the products on sale from the database and show it in my android app
I want to use this function (wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()) but which file I must include to define this function

I try to write this

```
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/' );
require_once (ABSPATH.'woocommerce/includes/wc-product-functions.php');
$array=wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();
```

but it show me Fatal errors of same codes in wc-product-functions.php

Q-which file I must include to define (wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()) 
is there an file in order to load the core functions of WooCommerce ?
I tried to require many files but no results

Comment: _"but it show me Fatal errors of same codes in wc-product-functions.php"_ - do you actually mean that you get a `Cannot redeclare xy` error message? In that case that would simply mean the function in question does already exist, so you probably don't need to include that file at all any more at this point. (Unless you are getting other errors in that case - but then please be specific, and quote the exact error message.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122882/how-to-use-woocommerce-functions-outside-of-wordpress

Comment: it show me many  "call to undefined function " errors ...I tried to include every file source it want ...Like  (...wp-includes/plugin.php ) for this error "Call to undefined function add_filter()"...after that it show me  "Call to undefined function get_transient()"  .....I want an core file for WooCommerce like (wp-load.php for wordpress)

Comment: According to the accepted answer in the duplicate you should not need anything more besides wp-load.php - have you at least tried that yet?

Comment: oo..yes thank you it work by adding wp-load.php ...before wc-product-functions.php